# outlook calendar connectivity with java web service

Tags: java, .net, jsp, outlook, synchronization

We currently have a java/jsp online web service that includes it's own custom calendar. I am trying to do some research into the possibility of connecting it to a users outlook. Our basic needs that are most simple is some way to sent the person a meeting request that can be added to their outlook from our service.

I know the ideal solution is to sync back and forth but simply being able to import the data from our calendar into someone's outlook would be sufficient.

Does anyone have any resources they can point me to that might help with information gathering, or any example/comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution to getting what we needed. Outlook can email an event invite, I had one emailed to me... then copied the format of the email and just have the system sending event invites as emails. That is sufficient for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample to sync calendars using javascript,ie and ActiveX
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OutlookDemo.aspx

Comment: great resource I will play with it and see how well it works. Do you know if it's cross browser or IE only?

Comment: @Isisagate Only IE will run ActiveX. If you want to run it from another browser, then you will need an extra process and need to talk to that.